# Jquery gets from value from option menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list

I have used a list with HTML, though when i try to get the item of the list it just returns "1" and not the options i have put in.

As for the list its the following:

```
<strong>Gender:</strong><span>
<select id="gender">
<option value="male">male</option>
<option value="female">female</option>
</select>
</span>
```

But when i try to get the value of it in jquery like so:

```
gen = $( "#gender option:selected" ).text();
```

It just returns 1 on both options. What did i do wrong?

Comment: `It just returns 1 on both options. What did i do wrong?` don't get u?

Answer (score 1):

Use `.val()` with select selector:

```
var value=$("#gender").val();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g8GC9/)**

Answer (score 0):

to get the value from form field use `val()` instead of `text()`

```
gen = $("#gender).val();
```